# Seperate site and admin in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Project Structure is

application
controllers/site
core/
views/site

I want when i entered `http://mywebsite` admin has to be loaded and when i entered `http://mywebsite/site` frontend has to be loaded

I went through some tutorials and i have done changes below

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['site'] = 'site/home';
```

In `core/My_Controller.php`

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Site_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In `controller/site/Home.php`

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

```
class Home extends Site_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("site/index.php");
    }
}
```

But I am getting 404 when I opened `http://mywebsite/site`

Please help me

Comment: Try with http://mywebsite/index.php/site

Comment: For that also i am getting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['site'] = 'site/home';
```

What that line does is that it defines a route that looks for a method called `home` inside the controller called Site viz. `Site_Controller`.

So you are getting the 404 error because your `Site_Controller` does not have the `home` method.

Try changing the `Site_Controller` like so...

```
class Site_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    # added this method
    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->view("site/index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: under which directory are you storing your controllers?